# How to use Binding in Xamarin.Forms (.XAML) using php script and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xamarin.forms, data-binding

**NEED HELP**

We are creating a Cross platform application in xamarin (Android / IOS). We have made a login system in our app by passing everytime when user is logged in, the Id of the user from the database. This Id is send to other pages in our app so that we could use this Id to access the other information (in other pages in our app) of that specific user with the specific Id.

Example:

We passed the Id to the profile page of the user that is logged in. As you can see in the screen beneath we want to get the username of that user so that we could use it in our app.

[image: 1]

When we pass the Id using a HTML page we get the correct data from the database as you can see. It is this content we want to show instead of "Username" (frist picture).

[image: 2]

The php-script we used to get this data out of our database (don't worry about mysql-injection the app is jsut for us we will change this later):

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'Antjim0809!','sendmeadrink_official');

$Id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Id']);

$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT Username from User WHERE Id = '$Id'");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $row['Username'];
}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

But when we try to get this information using Xamarin we get the 'null' instead of 'Lucino23' as you can see in the output:

[image: 3]

The Xamarin code of our Profile page looks like this (ProfilePage.XAML):

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
       Text="{Binding Username}"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       FontSize="30"/>
```

The code behind (ProfilePage.XAML.cs)

```
readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
    readonly user u = new user() { Id = string.Empty, Username = string.Empty, Email = string.Empty, Passwd = string.Empty, Age = string.Empty };

    public async void GetUserData(string Id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage res;
        u.Id = Id;

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Id", u.Id)
        });

        res = await client.PostAsync("http://10.0.2.2/*/*/*/UsernameById.php", content);
        u.Username = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(u.Username);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

    }
```

I resume: When we apply all the code above, the 'Username' (Picture 1) is empty and we cannot see the Username that tis stored in the database. So we want to replace the 'Username' by the string value in our database of a specific user that is logged in.

Thanks to all!

Comment: have you read the docs?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings

Comment: Yes i did but i can't really find out what i need to use of it in my code. It is a lot of information about binding and it is a bit messy for me...

Comment: 1. set the BindingContext, 2. you can only bind to public properties, 3. use INotifyPropertyChanged.  In your case setting `BIndingContext = u;` after you get your data will probably solve it

Comment: Could you clear this a bit up beacuse we don't really understand what you mean..

Comment: Add BindingContext = u; after you retrieve your data

Comment: @Jason Could you help me a bit by folowing the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682668/how-to-pass-data-of-specific-logged-in-user-to-xamarin-emulator-using-php-mysql

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, please post your answer and mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.